# RTSP server using Gstreamer in c

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

---

**UPDATE: i was able to solve this problem by turning off the firewalls.**

***But now i have another problem which is there's approx. 1 sec delay in the video playback.
Is there's any suggestions on how to improve the latency?***

---

I am attempting to build an RTSP server using Gstreamer to stream the built-in camera on my laptop. This setup works well when I use VLC as the client and stream locally.

However, when I try to connect another laptop on the same network, I obtain the IP address of the server laptop (192.168.1.2) and provide this URL (rtsp://192.168.1.2:8554/test) to VLC running on the client laptop.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and I'm uncertain about the source of the problem.

It's worth mentioning that I'm working on Windows 10.

Here's is my code

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>

 /* this timeout is periodically run to clean up the expired sessions from the
    * pool. This needs to be run explicitly currently but might be done
    * automatically as part of the mainloop. */
static gboolean

timeout(GstRTSPServer* server)
{
    GstRTSPSessionPool* pool;

    pool = gst_rtsp_server_get_session_pool(server);
    gst_rtsp_session_pool_cleanup(pool);
    g_object_unref(pool);

    return TRUE;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GMainLoop* loop;
    GstRTSPServer* server;
    GstRTSPMountPoints* mounts;
    GstRTSPMediaFactory* factory;

    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    /* create a server instance */
    server = gst_rtsp_server_new();
    gst_rtsp_server_set_address(server, "192.168.1.2");
    gst_rtsp_server_set_service(server, "8554");


    /* get the mount points for this server, every server has a default object
     * that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */
    mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);

    /* make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use
     * gst-launch syntax to create pipelines.
     * any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each
     * element with pay%d names will be a stream */
    factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();
    gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, "( "
        "ksvideosrc do-stats=TRUE ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480! "
        "videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 "
        "audiotestsrc ! audio/x-raw,rate=8000 ! "
        "alawenc ! rtppcmapay name=pay1 pt=97 " ")");

    /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
    gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, "/test", factory);

    /* don't need the ref to the mapper anymore */
    g_object_unref(mounts);

    /* attach the server to the default maincontext */
    if (gst_rtsp_server_attach(server, NULL) == 0)
        goto failed;

    /* add a timeout for the session cleanup */
    g_timeout_add_seconds(2, (GSourceFunc)timeout, server);

    /* start serving, this never stops */

    g_print("stream ready\n");
    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    return 0;

    /* ERRORS */
failed:
    {
        g_print("failed to attach the server\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know if Default rtsp protocol is rtsp/rtp/udp but for Testing Turn of Firewalls, to get sure u had no problem with that